# How do you go back to more than the first 5 chapters of Magicka?

Tags: magicka

I've been making progress in Magicka, and now I'm on chapter 8, however, I never picked up the teleport Magick in chapter 7, so I want to go back and get that in order to be able to cross a bridge. However, when I try to change chapters, I can only select from the first 5. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently exiting, playing a different game mode, and reentering made all of the levels I'd completed appear. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

Since the update 1.4.3.1, an option allows the player to revisit old chapters in a campaign. You just have to click on the name of the chapter on the select screen.

Changelog for Magicka Patch 1.4.3.1 2011-11-15

• Added saveable checkpoints. Checkpoints will now save your progress up to that point.

• Added a automatic-revive fairy for single player games.

• Added an option to revisit old chapters in a campaign.

• Improved server browser usability.

• Improved body collision detection and overall physics.

Comment: Yes, but I'm at what I believe is the select screen, and I only see the first five chapters, despite the fact that I'm currently on chapter eight. I'm talking about the select screen you get when you click on the map. Is that what you're referring to?